convert the current UTC time to micro seconds format in C#
How to represent current UTC date time in the following format
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ
I tried this:
Convert.ToDatetime(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ")

o/p : 2024-05-10T01:56:36:36Z
But the problem is I am getting the seconds restricted to two digits instead of 3 even if I specify "sssZ"

You're doing ss.sss, did you mean ss.fff instead? And if you really mean "millionths of a second", you're going to need more "f"s. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

You want ss.fffZ, not ss.sssZ

@gunr2171, there is no intellisense for ss.fffZ . It is automatically getting converting to ss.dZ in Quickwatch.

Three-digit-fractions of a second resolve to millseconds by the way (10³). Microseconds would have six-digits (10⁶). $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffffZ}" // µs $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ}" // ms

Regardless of Intellisense, ffffff is what you want, for microseconds. See the link from the first comment.

@VA1267 I'm not sure what you're talking about. Works fine for me. https://dotnetfiddle.net/qDv7a4

Time formatting codes can be quite complex (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  Currently you are using:
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ
Which breaks down into:

yyyy - year as a four digit value
-    - literal character '-'
MM   - month as a two digit value 
-    - literal character '-'
dd   - day of month as a two digit value
T    - literal character 'T'
hh   - hour of day as a two digit, 00-12 value
:    - literal character ':'
mm   - minute of hour as a two digit value
:    - literal character ':'
ss   - second of minute as a two digit value
ss   - second of minute as a two digit value (duplicate?)
s    - second of minute as a one digit value (duplicate?)
Z    - as the literal character 'Z'


I'm a bit surprised that last 's' didn't render an additional '36'.
What I suspect you might want is
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"
Which produces a non ambiguous hour value (00-23) and fractions of a second time in milliseconds
If you actually want "micro seconds" as suggested in your questions title you will need to use 'ffffff' instead of 'fff'.

If you are using string.Format to print a decimal, you can do something like this:
string.Format("{0:00.00}", 1.23456m) // prints "01.23"

The format here, 00.00, is similar to what you're trying to do with displaying seconds, ss.sss.
Unfortunately, you can't do the same trick with DateTimes. If you want to show fractional seconds, you need to use a different symbol - f.
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ


The "fff" custom format specifier represents the three most significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the milliseconds in a date and time value. Source

However, if you really want "millionths of a second", you need more f's. 6 of them in fact.

The "ffffff" custom format specifier represents the six most significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the millionths of a second in a date and time value.

So your final code would be
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ")


.UtcNow is already a DateTime, no need to use Convert.ToDatetime
hh is 12-hour time. I'm guessing you actually want HH which is 24-hour time.

See Custom date and time format strings for the full listing of available symbols and their meanings.

string formattedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");


Code only answers are typically not good quality answers. Please consider making an [edit] to your post to explain the code modifications.

Try this:
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string formattedDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
        Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
    }
}


Code only answers are typically not good quality answers. Please consider making an [edit] to your post to explain the code modifications.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
